# How do you merge 2 areas of a single mesh into one?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

I am a newbie to Blender and am trying to create my own character off of a template I found online. I duplicated my arms to edit them separately. After that, I tried to join the 2 meshes with "Ctrl+J" but Blender only shows one meshes. I tried to use the "F" key but that didn't work either.

Can someone please help me get an arm onto my body. Also, I don't have the armature in place yet.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are watching sebastian lague's video.

Now that you have created arms and the body, you want to join them. First, I must tell you that ctrl+J only makes joins meaning it doesn't join the faces or vertices but it makes both the mesh to be accessible by one name. 
Now for joining the hands with the body you need to follow these steps:-

1. You need to select two vertices one of the hand and other vertice of
   the body nearest to the vertice selected before.
2. Press  alt + m while selecting the vertices. Select 'to center' and
   now your the vertices are joined.
3. Repeat this step for all vertices.

The other way :-

1. Select your hand by hovering over it and press 'l'. Now you have
   your hand selected.
2. Press P to separate the hand. This is the opposite of Ctrl + J.
3. Exit Edit mode.
4. Select your hand mesh and enter edit mode to extend the edges near
   the top say shoulder.
5. Extend them by pressing E. So that the extended part touches the
   body. Try to make the extended part as small as possible.
6. Now Exit Edit mode.
7. Go to modifiers tab and select boolean.
8. Select Union in boolean and then select your body mesh. Click Apply.
9. Now you have both the mesh joined. You can delete your body mesh
   now.

I would recommend to follow the first way.

Hope this helps.